# How are Windows 10 hashes stored if the account is setup using a Microsoft account?

Tags: hash, windows, ntlm

I was testing the integrity of my passwords and noticed that after I dumped the hashes, there was only one account where the NTLM hash was not a "default hash." I also know that that account happens to be my backup user so it is not configured to log into any Microsoft account. It is simply a local user.

On the other hand, my main account is configured to be a Microsoft account and its hash is the default 31d6cfe0d16ae931b73c59d7e0c089c0, which is really an empty password. However, that is not my real password on the account.

So my question is, is that the hash because when I log in using a Microsoft account, is it making a request to the Microsoft servers for the hash/validation or is the hash stored anywhere else.

Also, wouldn't it be more secure for a person to be forced to use a Microsoft account because a hacker would never be able to take advantage of physical access to a machine or tricking the user to click on something that gives them access to the SAM/SYSTEM files?

Answer (score 31):

Windows hashes are saved in [`SAM`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Accounts_Manager) file (encrypted with [`SYSTEM`](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/63890/does-windows-have-a-built-in-password-store) file) on your computer regardless of the fact that you are using [Microsoft account](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_account). It needs to be done this way to allow you to log in to your computer, even if you are not connected to the internet. If you change your password using [account.microsoft.com](https://account.microsoft.com/), you will still be able to log in to your computer with your old password (even if you are using [Microsoft account](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_account)). After logging in to the system, you will be prompted to type new password, but as long as you don't type new password, you will be able to use old password to log in to your computer. After you type new password, [`SAM`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Accounts_Manager) (and possibly [`SYSTEM`](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/63890/does-windows-have-a-built-in-password-store)) file will be updated.

You (wrongly) get [`31d6cfe0d16ae931b73c59d7e0c089c0`](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=31d6cfe0d16ae931b73c59d7e0c089c0&ia=web) hash of your password because format of the [`SAM`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Accounts_Manager) and/or [`SYSTEM`](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/63890/does-windows-have-a-built-in-password-store) files has [changed](https://twitter.com/gentilkiwi/status/762465220132384770) since [*Windows 10 Anniversary update*](http://www.computerworld.com/article/3101968/microsoft-windows/review-windows-10-anniversary-update-good-bad-meh-video.html) (see: [similar problem](https://github.com/Neohapsis/creddump7/issues/2)), thus tools like [`chntpw`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chntpw), [`bkhive`](https://samsclass.info/124/proj14/bkhive.htm), [`pwdump`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pwdump), [`samdump2`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/samdump2) print hash of the empty password (I verified it on my Windows 10). Since this update, Windows [uses](https://github.com/gentilkiwi/mimikatz/commit/823d376d8044e112acd1e03225a5eba0e97d0397#diff-39b5f01b7245d741154f25ae7fe8eb96R358) [AES128](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) to encrypt password's [MD4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD4) hash. Because of that, nearly all tutorials [regarding](https://hashcrack.org/page?n=20042015) [Windows password](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chntpw) [recovery](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/) became outdated.

Fortunately there is a [tool](https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/Mimikatz/) called [`mimikatz`](https://github.com/gentilkiwi/mimikatz) (Windows-only, but can be ran on Linux by using [Wine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_(software))) created by [Benjamin](https://twitter.com/gentilkiwi) [Delpy](https://www.linkedin.com/in/delpy), that can read passwords' hashes saved in Windows' new format. Note that [Windows Defender](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Defender) and Symantec antivirus [treats it](https://www.symantec.com/security_response/writeup.jsp?docid=2012-042615-3731-99) as a [*'Hack Tool'*](https://www.symantec.com/security_response/writeup.jsp?docid=2001-081707-2550-99) and removes it, so you need to disable them before running [`mimikatz`](https://github.com/gentilkiwi/mimikatz) (run as a administrator).

[`mimikatz`](https://github.com/gentilkiwi/mimikatz) consists of [many modules](https://github.com/gentilkiwi/mimikatz/wiki#modules), but you should explore [`lsadump`](https://github.com/gentilkiwi/mimikatz/wiki/module-~-lsadump) module, particularly [`lsadump::sam`](https://alexandreborgesbrazil.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/mimikatz.pdf) function.

[Excerpt](https://github.com/gentilkiwi/mimikatz/wiki/module-~-lsadump) from [docs](https://github.com/gentilkiwi/mimikatz/wiki#modules):

> If you're not `SYSTEM` or using an impersonated `SYSTEM` token, you'll have access denied error:
>
> ```
> mimikatz # lsadump::sam
> Domain : VM-W7-ULT-X
> SysKey : 74c159e4408119a0ba39a7872e9d9a56
> ERROR kuhl_m_lsadump_getUsersAndSamKey ; kull_m_registry_RegOpenKeyEx SAM Accounts (0x00000005)
> ```
>
> In this case, you can use `psexec` to begin `SYSTEM` (or other tools) or elevate with `token::elevate` command to impersonate a `SYSTEM` token:
>
> ```
> mimikatz # privilege::debug
> Privilege '20' OK
>
> mimikatz # token::whoami
>  * Process Token : 623884       vm-w7-ult-x\Gentil Kiwi S-1-5-21-1982681256-1210654043-1600862990-1000  (14g,24p)       Primary
>  * Thread Token  : no token
>
> mimikatz # token::elevate
> Token Id  : 0
> User name :
> SID name  : AUTORITE NT\Système
>
> 228     24215           AUTORITE NT\Système     S-1-5-18        (04g,30p)       Primary
>  -> Impersonated !
>  * Process Token : 623884       vm-w7-ult-x\Gentil Kiwi S-1-5-21-1982681256-1210654043-1600862990-1000  (14g,24p)       Primary
>  * Thread Token  : 624196       AUTORITE NT\Système     S-1-5-18        (04g,30p)       Impersonation (Delegation)
>
> mimikatz # lsadump::sam
> Domain : VM-W7-ULT-X
> SysKey : 74c159e4408119a0ba39a7872e9d9a56
>
> SAMKey : e44dd440fd77ebfe800edf60c11d4abd
>
> RID  : 000001f4 (500)
> User : Administrateur
> LM   :
> NTLM : 31d6cfe0d16ae931b73c59d7e0c089c0
>
> RID  : 000001f5 (501)
> User : Invité
> LM   :
> NTLM :
>
> RID  : 000003e8 (1000)
> User : Gentil Kiwi
> LM   :
> NTLM : cc36cf7a8514893efccd332446158b1a
> ```

You can download [`x86`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86) and [`amd64`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64) binaries of the [`mimikatz`](https://github.com/gentilkiwi/mimikatz) [here](https://github.com/gentilkiwi/mimikatz/releases).

As a side note – if you want to make sure that password's hash is hash of your password, you can easily [do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15603628/how-to-calculate-ntlm-hash-in-python) it using [Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)):

```
user@mycompa:~$  python3
Python 3.5.3 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:11:04) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170118] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import hashlib, binascii
>>> passwd = "password"
>>> hash = hashlib.new('md4', passwd.encode('utf-16le')).digest()
>>> print(binascii.hexlify(hash))
b'8846f7eaee8fb117ad06bdd830b7586c'
```

Comment: why not use hexdigest() instead of digest followed by hexlify?

Answer (score 1):

To add onto [patryk.beza's](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/158174/185377) good answer:

> Also, wouldn't it be more secure for a person to be forced to use a Microsoft account because a hacker would never be able to take advantage of physical access to a machine or tricking the user to click on something that gives them access to the SAM/SYSTEM files?

No, the password has to be stored on your computer somewhere.  If for some reason you can't access the MS servers when you log in, the OS will still let you login with your credentials.  And even though the user didn't click on anything, it's still possible that a potential flaw in the OS will give a threat actor access to the `SAM` file.  One of the major problems that I have with the MS accounts is this: when you link your MS account to your computer, it uses the same password for everything.  This can be very bad since a threat actor can change your password if they can get access to the `SAM` file and break the hashing.  If a threat actor has your password, they can start changing all of your passwords to completely lock you out of everything.  It's a major risk that MS doesn't tell you about since they like being able to spy on you.  And it's only a matter of time before more [rainbow tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) come out to start breaking Windows 10 passwords.  When it comes to security, it's never a question of **IF**; it's **WHEN**.

Comment: The solution is to use TPM-bound credentials, which exploit non-exportability and rate limiting by the TPM. This is how Windows Hello (consumer PINs) and Windows Hello For Business (domain credentials) are done today.